# Woocommerce задать произвольный id товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Использую интеграцию *woo-retailcrm-мойсклад*, товары синхронизируются по `id` (*Woocommerce*), выгружаются из *Woocommerce* через YML.

Встала задача приходовать товары в моем складе и выгружать на сайт с *Woocommerce* через API.

Можно ли создавать товар в *Woocommerce* c заданным `id (set_id())` или нужно обязательно переходить на использование артикулов, то есть синхронизировать товары по артикулам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Товар в WooCommerce - это пост WordPress кастомного типа product. Все посты в WordPress должны иметь уникальный id. В том числе страницы, записи, меню, и т.д.

Вы не можете быть уверенным, что id товара уже не занят другим объектом в WordPress. Поэтому синхронизация по id - нерешаемая задача.

Для товаров специально введён sku, как идентификатор товара.